# How to get rid of navigation symbols in beamer?

Tags: beamer, symbols, navigation

When creating presentations in [`beamer`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer), those little symbols that you can click on and will take you to different parts of your presentation are automatically included on your slides.

I don't like that, but decided not to try and change it for now. The problem is that when I gave my presentation to my supervisor to revise, the first thing he did was cross the symbols out in red, meaning: take this out!

What should I do? Is there an easy command to get rid of those symbols or do I have to change the theme of my presentation to get rid of the symbols?

Comment: While I'd agree that the navigation symbols aren't really what @Vivi was likely to want feedback on, I must commend her supervisor for his aesthetic sense.

Comment: Supervisor's right!  99% of the time, those symbols are only good for  advertising your use of beamer.

Answer (score 184, accepted):

In addition to Michael's way, there is the slightly different

```
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
```

that I've been using in my preambles.

Comment: Michael's answer uses a general mechanism, and generality is good. But, I do like this one for its self-documentation.

Answer (score 137):

It can be done with one quick command!  Just put

```
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
```

before your `\begin{document}` to clear the navigation symbols.

Comment: If you want to customize the beamer symbols, refer to page 73-74 of http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf