# Remove control bar from beamer presentations

Tags: beamer, navigation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get rid of navigation symbols in beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/686/how-to-get-rid-of-navigation-symbols-in-beamer)

By standard, Beamer presentations display a bar that lets you jump through your slides at the bottom. How can I remove that one?

Comment: Thanks, t is indeed, but as you say it is very hard to find that...