# How to remove buttons from the bottom of Madrid theme?

Tags: beamer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get rid of navigation symbols in beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/686/how-to-get-rid-of-navigation-symbols-in-beamer)

I am not sure what they are called, but there is a bar of buttons in the Madrid theme, just above the page numbering, that looks like this:
[image]
I would really like to not have the white buttons appear (but leave the page numbering intact).

Does anyone know how I can do this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Put `\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}` in your preamble.