# Modify footer of slides

Tags: beamer, header-footer, footnotes, themes

I am editing a presentation with `beamer`, the theme is `Boadilla`:

```
\date{date}
\title[The title is quite quite quite quite quite quite long]{The title is quite quite quite quite quite quite long}
\author{My name}
\institute{My school}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
```

[image]

There are several things I would like to change:

1) When I open the pdf file in "Slideshow" mode, the list of buttons on the right bottom is still visible, I don't think it is necessary, could anyone tell me how to remove it?

2) On the bottom, there are currently 3 parts. For the 1st part, `My school` is appended automatically after `My name`, is it possible to remove `My school`?

3) I don't think `date` is necessary, which is the 3rd part. Is it possible to just remove this part, so that I have more space for the title + page number? If it is not possible, I would prefer to put the name of `Section` at the 2nd part instead of the title, does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can redefine the `footline` template as defined by the `infolines` outer theme (internally used by the `Boadilla` theme); `\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}` will remove tha navigation symbols:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}

\makeatother
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.4\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.6\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle\hspace*{3em}
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{1ex}
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\date{date}
\title[The title is quite quite quite quite quite quite long]{The title is quite quite quite quite quite quite long}
\author{My name}
\institute{My school}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi is there any way how to have all 3 section but change the proportions?

Comment: @DusanPlavak please feel free to ask a follow-up question. You can provide there a link to this one as background-

Answer (score 10):

You could change the outer theme and use one with two parts, such as the `split` theme. Load it after loading `Boadilla`. The second line is for [removing the navigation symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/686/how-to-get-rid-of-navigation-symbols-in-beamer):

```
\useoutertheme{split}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
```

(My school) is gone, date is gone, two parts. Perhaps you just like to adjust the color later, if you don't like the white on black color introduced by split.

[image: Boadilla with split footline]