# modify beamer footer portions

Tags: beamer, header-footer

I have a small problem because I have quite a long title of my presentation so it is overflowing in footline...

Is there any way how to change portion of these 3 parts in footline? 
I think that 1/3 just for page number is too much in my case...

Thanks...

also I am aware of that solution:[Modify footer of slides](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66995/modify-footer-of-slides)

but it is slightly different.

Without navigation symbols:

[image]

with navigation symbols:
[image]

There is amissing color change if I will not use the navigation symbols.

Comment: Are you using the same theme as in the answer linked or are you using a different theme?

Comment: I`m using CambridgeUS

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Notice that you can use the optional argument for `\title`, as in

```
\title[<short version>]{<long version>}
```

to provide a shorter version of the title for the footline. If this is not an option, then see below.

You can place the three elements (author,title and page counting) in different `beamercolorbox`es and adjust their width to suit your needs (change the `wd=<length>` parameters making sure the three lengths add up to `1\textwidth`):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\makeatother
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.3\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.6\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.1\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{date in head/foot}%
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{1ex}
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\date{date}
\title[The title is quite quite quite quite quite quite long]{The title is quite quite quite quite quite quite long}
\author{My name}
\institute{My school}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A zoomed image of the footline:

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the answer is there any way that the third beamrcolorbox will have the same color as it would if it will be in navigation symbols?

Comment: @DusanPlavak sure. The problem is just that I don't know what color are you talking about. Can you please try to describe (or better yet, give an image of) the desired color?

Comment: well I am using CambridgeUS template, but point is that if I put the colorcode then  will have change it every time when I will changing template... anyway editing my question with img

Comment: @DusanPlavak So you want fixed colors for the boxes?

Comment: nope I want to avoid the fixed colors in my code if it is possible..

Comment: @DusanPlavak Then my solution is what you want, I am *not* using fixed colors. The colors used will change if you switch themes. Perhaps then I still don't understand the color problem?

Comment: I just updated question with another picture where you can see color differences

Comment: @DusanPlavak I now I think I understand. Please see my updated answer. Is it something like that what you want?