# How to make this custom footer in beamer?

Tags: beamer, header-footer

I would like to create a custom footer like this one in Beamer ? How can I do it and set it for all or some slides ?

[image: custom footer]

I want to use the stockholm beamer theme [(link)](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/stockholm-beamer-theme/xjysnqdxfjbc#.Vc0RLHgZggM)
but I did not like the footer so I wanted to change it to this one.

Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: Welcome! Please provide a small, compilable sample document. Without knowing your current Beamer config, it isn't possible to say very much. We don't know which themes or options you are using, how the colours relate to your colour theme. Etc.

Comment: Related: [Modify footer of slides](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66995/modify-footer-of-slides)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here you go (adjust the settings according to your needs):

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\usetheme{sthlm}

\usepackage{
booktabs,
datetime,
dtklogos,
multicol,
pgfplots,
ragged2e,
tabularx,
tikz,
wasysym
}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}

\usetikzlibrary{
backgrounds,
mindmap
}

\setbeameroption{show notes}

\title{The title}
\subtitle{The subtitle}
\date{\today}
\author{The Author}
\institute{The Institute}

\hypersetup{
pdfauthor = {Mark H. Olson: sayhi@hendryolson.com},      
pdfsubject = {Mathematics, },
pdfkeywords = {},  
pdfmoddate= {D:\pdfdate},          
pdfcreator = {WriteLaTeX}
}

\definecolor{footcolor1}{RGB}{10,169,220}
\definecolor{footcolor2}{RGB}{161,229,78}
\definecolor{footcolor3}{RGB}{255,205,0}
\definecolor{footcolor4}{RGB}{182,232,230}
\definecolor{footcolor5}{RGB}{193,239,155}

\setbeamercolor{box1}{fg=black,bg=footcolor1}
\setbeamercolor{box2}{fg=black,bg=footcolor2}
\setbeamercolor{box3}{fg=black,bg=footcolor3}
\setbeamercolor{box4}{fg=black,bg=footcolor4}
\setbeamercolor{box5}{fg=black,bg=footcolor5}

\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{mytheme}{
\leavevmode
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.15\paperwidth,sep=1em]{box1}
\usebeamercolor{author in head/foot}\insertframenumber
\end{beamercolorbox}\hfill%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.12\paperwidth,sep=1em]{box2}
\phantom{A}
\end{beamercolorbox}\hfill%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.12\paperwidth,sep=1em]{box3}
\phantom{A}
\end{beamercolorbox}\hfill%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.12\paperwidth,sep=1em]{box4}
\phantom{A}
\end{beamercolorbox}\hfill%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.4\paperwidth,sep=1em]{box5}
\hfill\usebeamercolor{author in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
\end{beamercolorbox}%
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Background}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A test frame}
Some test text
\begin{block}{A test block}
\begin{itemize}
  \item point 1
  \item point 2
\end{itemize}
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Of course, you can use this footline with any theme you like; you only need to add the `footline` definition:

```
\definecolor{footcolor1}{RGB}{10,169,220}
\definecolor{footcolor2}{RGB}{161,229,78}
\definecolor{footcolor3}{RGB}{255,205,0}
\definecolor{footcolor4}{RGB}{182,232,230}
\definecolor{footcolor5}{RGB}{193,239,155}

\setbeamercolor{box1}{fg=black,bg=footcolor1}
\setbeamercolor{box2}{fg=black,bg=footcolor2}
\setbeamercolor{box3}{fg=black,bg=footcolor3}
\setbeamercolor{box4}{fg=black,bg=footcolor4}
\setbeamercolor{box5}{fg=black,bg=footcolor5}

\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{mytheme}{
\leavevmode
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.15\paperwidth,sep=1em]{box1}
\usebeamercolor{author in head/foot}\insertframenumber
\end{beamercolorbox}\hfill%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.12\paperwidth,sep=1em]{box2}
\phantom{A}
\end{beamercolorbox}\hfill%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.12\paperwidth,sep=1em]{box3}
\phantom{A}
\end{beamercolorbox}\hfill%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.12\paperwidth,sep=1em]{box4}
\phantom{A}
\end{beamercolorbox}\hfill%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.4\paperwidth,sep=1em]{box5}
\hfill\usebeamercolor{author in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
\end{beamercolorbox}%
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I almost figured it out before you posted the answer. I had some problems of horizontal spacing but your solution is perfect. Thank you !

Comment: @AbdulWahab You're welcome!