# How to disable page shortcut without changing the theme

Tags: beamer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get rid of navigation symbols in beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/686/how-to-get-rid-of-navigation-symbols-in-beamer)

How can I remove the page-shortcut symbols that appear below the frames? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you mean these :

[image]

You can add this line to your presentation settings :

```
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
```

For example :

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation> {
  \usetheme{Warsaw}      % or whichever one you're using...
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
}

\title{Title}

\author{Name}

\date{Today}

\subject{Presentation}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```