# Remove the space produced by navigation symbols

Tags: beamer, header-footer, navigation, mini-frames

I am using the Dresden scheme.
I know how to remove the symbols with

```
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{mini frames}{}
```

but there is still a space left below the section. How do I eliminate it? The upper bar in the header is supposed to have the same height as the lower bar in the header.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Does this http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/686/14757 help you?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `beamer` theme `Dresden` uses a so-called *mini frame navigation*, i. e. little circles each representing one slide. With `\setbeamertemplate{mini frames}{}`, you can remove these, but the space is still occupied:

[image: headline without mini frames, but with spurious space]

To get rid of this gap, you have two possibilities:

1. Remove all `\subsection` commands from your presentation.  Mini frames are only created [if there is a subsection present](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2072/3323).
2. Add `\renewcommand*{\slideentry}[6]{}` to the preamble of your document (the part between `\documentclass{beamer}`  and `\begin{document}`). This empties the internal `beamer` macro responsible for generating the mini frames and the space around them:

   ```
   \documentclass{beamer}

   \usetheme{Dresden}
   \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
   \setbeamertemplate{mini frames}{}
   \renewcommand*{\slideentry}[6]{}

   \begin{document}
   \section{Section 1}
   \subsection{Subsection 1}
   \frame{}\frame{}\frame{}
   \subsection{Subsection 2}
   \frame{}\frame{}
   \section{Section 2}
   \subsection{Subsection 1}
   \frame{}\frame{}
   \subsection{Subsection 2}
   \frame{}\frame{}\frame{}\frame{}\frame{}\frame{}
   \end{document}
   ```

   [image: same headline as above, but without empty gap]

Comment: Thank you for this fast and excellent answer. 2. worked perfectly.