# Using pstool with beamer

Tags: beamer, psfrag

I would like to use `pstool` with `beamer` to create a presentation in `pdflatex` with figures processed by `psfrag`. However, as the simple example below shows, the figures are processed using the `beamer` documentclass, so that they each have a full `beamer` "frame" around them. Is there a way around this?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[process=all,crop=pdfcrop]{pstool}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Circle}
    \begin{figure}
        \psfragfig[width=0.3\textwidth]{figures/circle}
        {
            \psfrag{1}{\(s\)}
        }
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

I suspect that if it's possible to override the documentclass used by `pstool` to process the figures, that would be a solution, but I haven't found how to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: I should add that I'm on a fully updated version of Tex Live 2013 (on Linux, if that matters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to solving this is to realise that a "regular" compilation process sends your document through pdfLaTeX in PDF mode, and in order to do the `psfrag` replacements the graphic is sent through pdfLaTeX in DVI mode.

Therefore, conditional commands for either the main document only or each graphic only can simply use `\ifpdf`:

```
\ifpdf
  % setup for the main document only
\else
  % setup for pstool images only
\fi
```

And so in your case:

```
\ifpdf\else
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\fi
```

This is entirely unmentioned in the documentation, so I'll go fix that up now.

Answer (score 3):

`pstool` package uses the preamble of main document class(in your Q it is beamer) to build the pdf figures during the underhood auxiliary processing (`latex-dvips-ps2pdf`) of  `.eps` figure and psfrag commands. So to get a `circle.pdf` figure without navigation bar add

```
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
```

in the preamble after `\documentclass{beamer}`as shown in
[How to get rid of navigation symbols in beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/686/how-to-get-rid-of-navigation-symbols-in-beamer) and compile with `pdflatex -shell-escape` gives

[image]

Once you have all pdf figures are generated via auxiliary processing.  Set the option `process=none` instead of `process=all` and comment out the *only* line  like this 
`%\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}` to process beamer slides with figures (navigation bar less) and finally you will get navigation bar on main beamer slides.

Note: `\EndPreamble` can be used to limit the preamble used for auxiliary processing and thereby speed it up. More details refer [pstool documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/pstool/pstool.pdf)

Comment: This sounds very promising. I'll try it when I get a chance and let you know how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: However, it does seem like this would get rid of the navigation symbols for the actual presentation as well as the embedded figures. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: @mjrussell Navigation bar symbols will be added once you comment `%\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}` and set `process=none` since we have already generated pdf figures(without navigation symbol).

Comment: It's a bit of a "manual" process, but it should work I guess. Thanks. I wonder if there is a nice way to automate this

Comment: @mjrussell No to my knowledge, but you may post it as feature request to `remove navigation symbols in figures with beamer class with pstool` at Package authors github's repo https://github.com/wspr/pstool/issues

Comment: Creating an issue now

Answer (score 0):

The same issue appears when using a {background canvas}-image. So here is an extension of @Will's solution in the case of using a {background canvas}-image.

```
 \ifpdf
    \setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
    \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{my_background_image}  
    }
 \else
     \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
     \setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{}
 \fi
```