# Wrong eps to pdf conversion under beamer using pstools

Tags: beamer, pstool

EDITED 2: It is a duplicate of [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167489/using-pstool-with-beamer/645616#645616). I had the same issue when using a {background canvas}-image and I've added a modified fix (in this case) in the above link.

EDITED 1: This issue has today been posted [here](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/773).

When converting, under *beamer documentclass*, an eps file to a pdf file using \fragfig command from the pstool package, the generated pdf file takes the whole beamer background and its size is corrupted which is NOT desired.

In the minimum (non-) working example shown below, the eps-file :

> ExampleFig.eps

is converted to

> ExampleFig.pdf

and yields the following file with a wrong size and the footline from beamer, which is NOT desired.

[image]

By changing the *documentclass* to *article* the CORRECT pdf file is generated (as in the image below).

[image]

Note that I'm talking about eps to pdf conversion and not about the global tex to pdf!

Any fix? Any workaround?

Below is the minimum example. The eps file can be downloaded from [here](https://malti.fr/images/ExampleFigeps.zip) and unzipped in the same directory.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[crop=pdfcrop,process=all]{pstool} 
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h!]
        \centering
        \psfragfig[scale=0.2]{ExampleFig}{
        \psfrag{AB}[][r]{\scalebox{1}{$G(p)$}}          
        }  
    \end{figure}
 \end{document}
```

Compilation:
pdftex --file-line-error --synctex=1 --shell-escape

Comment: Please make your MWE compilable. Your link is not secure, consequently not accessible.

Comment: @Zarko, the link is now secured. The zipped file needs to be unzipped in the same directory.