# Excluding page numbers from appendix in beamer

Tags: beamer, page-numbering, conditionals, appendices, etoolbox

I used the accepted answer from [How to insert page number in Beamer Navigation Bars?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137022/how-to-insert-page-number-in-beamer-navigation-bars) to insert the page number in beamers navigation bar. But I am trying to exclude the page numbers from the appendix. The appendix is not counted as intended but it should just be one page saying something like “time for question” without any additional content (like page numbers). Even worse, in the current version I have to chose between a page number which is not correct or a page number that is bigger than the actual number of pages (if you remove `[noframenumbering]`)

My minimum “working” example:

```
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext, ngerman]{beamer}
\usepackage{etoolbox} % for \newtoggle and \iftoggle

\usetheme{Frankfurt}

% see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/686/how-to-get-rid-of-navigation-symbols-in-beamer
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\newtoggle{inAppendix}
\newcommand{\myAppendix}{\appendix\toggletrue{inAppendix}}
% see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137022/how-to-insert-page-number-in-beamer-navigation-bars (I modified this)
\addtobeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}{
    \iftoggle{inAppendix}{}% do nothing in appendix
    {% add number of frame
        \usebeamerfont{footline}%
        \usebeamercolor[fg]{footline}%
        \hspace{1em}%
        \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber
    }
}
\setbeamercolor{footline}{fg=black}

\title{Awesome project}
\author{Nomen nescio}

\begin{document}
    \frame{\titlepage}
    \frame{\tableofcontents[pausesections]}
    \section{Test}

    \begin{frame}
        Stuff!
    \end{frame}

    \myAppendix
    \begin{frame}[noframenumbering]
        \Huge
        Time for questions.
    \end{frame}
\end{document}}
```

My idea was to use a toggle for checking whether I have to add the page number. I tried replacing the toggle with a `\newif\ifAppendix` but it has nothing to do with it. I think I am checking the condition to late and the page number is already typeset when changing the value of the toggle.

What is happening in the background causing the toggle to have no effect? How can I get an output without page numbers in the appendix?

Comment: Do you really need the headline on that frame?

Comment: Your problem is the option `ignorenonframetext` which causes your solution to break. Without that option you could also use the `plain` frame option. If you can omit this option (because you do not have `beamerarticle` content), your problem is solved.

Comment: This would be a solution, but samcarter found an even better one ;-).

Comment: I noticed it and it is really good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext, ngerman]{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\addtobeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}{
    \ifnum\insertframenumber>\inserttotalframenumber%
        \relax
    \else%
      \usebeamerfont{footline}%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{footline}%
    \hspace{1em}%
    \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber
  \fi%
}
\setbeamercolor{footline}{fg=black}

\title{Awesome project}
\author{Nomen nescio}

\begin{document}
    \frame{\titlepage}
    \frame{\tableofcontents[pausesections]}
    \section{Test}

    \begin{frame}
        Stuff!
    \end{frame}

    \appendix
    \begin{frame}
        \Huge
        Time for questions.
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Starting with beamer version 3.49 the solution can be simplified to

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{
    \ifbeamer@inappendix%
  \else%
    \usebeamerfont{footline}%
        \usebeamercolor[fg]{footline}%
    \insertframenumber\,/\,\insertmainframenumber%
  \fi%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \section{Test}

    \begin{frame}
        Stuff!
    \end{frame}

    \appendix
    \begin{frame}
        \Huge
        Time for questions.
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: None of the solutions work for me. I use the `Madrid` theme.

Comment: @HoseinRahnama As the madrid theme uses a footline, maybe use `\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}{...}`, but it is hard to diagnose without seeing your code

Comment: Yeah! that does the trick. :)